# Why not use the user UID as a key for the other tables?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen many examples of Firebase but I was wondering why someone did not use the UID as a key to the tables. An example here is that of the relationship 1 to N, in this case a user with UID 101 has N workouts. To get his workouts I read from the workout table and find UID 101 and read all his workouts. This image is only an example. I would like to understand in the case of 1 to N relationships if it can be a good idea and if it isn't, why? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I use uid as the key of many nodes in my database. It is often the most logical and efficient way to access the data related to a specific user.

Comment: OK thanks. I felt foolish to ask this question because I saw many who first use the id of the table and under it the UID, but so in my opinion the search should be slower.

Comment: By 'id of the table' I assume you mean the key generated by fb rtdb when you do a 'push' call to add the record? I only use these generated keys for transactional records eg chat messages. For all data related to a user, I will use the uid. It is pointless generating a push key and then storing the uid under it, in these cases.

Comment: I'll explain better. I will only use Firebase as a kind of backup. I will read the data only at login because I have everything locally. So if the user as in this case creates a new workout I will send the data of the workout table. Since most of the ids are created locally, I was thinking of using the user UID and under the UID enter the id I already have locally based on the table. For example if I am sending the workout in this case I position myself on workout-> user UID-> id that I have locally in the workout table ...

Comment: Not sure I fully understand but seems like dealing with two ids for the same user is overly complicated and could introduce errors. Also, it makes retrieving data from fb (if you ever wanted to) more complicated given your local key is not the fb key. Could you not use FB authentication to generate a key for a user and then use that locally and on the db?

Comment: I had already created the local database, so now I have many active users, I can't go back. In reality this does not seem to me a problem because from the UID, I switch to the id of the table and then I have the data returned. Actually I have seen that with this logic I get up to 5-6 nodes grafted, but I don't think it is a problem because as explained above I have written more times than I read data.In this case it is as if all the tables are 1 to N with User. Because under each table on Firebase I have the UID to access the individual user.

Comment: Fair enough. :-)